# like the back of their hand or like the back of their hands

Tags: idioms

Should "hand" go in the plural in this idiom "like the back of their hand(s)"?

Grammarly corrects me to use the plural, but I doubt it.

I think it's the doubt of the same origin as "they had to make up their mind(s)."

Comment: Like the **backs** of their **hands**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singular "hand", for the gender-neutral "their". This is the case when need a third-person pronoun, but don't want to use "his" or "her".

> The person that we hire should know Python like the back of their hand.

(That is too casual for a job specification, it is just to illustrate the point)

But perhaps plural "hands" for plural "their".

> My three children spent all summer playing in the woods.  Now they know the woods like the backs of their hands.